# Redefinition + Conflicting types errors, but nothing is being redefined or actually conflicting

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, esp32, esp-idf

I am getting some errors I'm not really understanding, nor a solution to get around them.

I am working on a ESP32 Bluetooth connection using esp-IDF, VSCode, and PlatformIO.

I have a section of code

```
esp_hid_gap_init(ESP_BT_MODE_BTDM);
esp_ble_gattc_register_callback(esp_hidh_gattc_event_handler);
esp_hidh_config_t config = {
    .callback = hidh_callback,
};
ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_hidh_init(&config) );
btkeyboard_queue_init();
ESP_ERROR_CHECK( err );
```

That is initialising Bluetooth and looking for connections, it requires the use of a header called bluetoothkeyboard.h which i pulled from: https://github.com/bozont/Duke3D/tree/master/components/SDL/bluetoothkeyboard

When i include this header in my main.c i get 11 errors, 10 from bluetoothkeyboard.h and one from SDL_event.h (also in the github repo i linked) they are:

[image: errors]

The code is all unmodified and it clearly works in his demo and many others who have used it and I'm not keen on messing with a third-party library, I just don't understand what's going on and how to move around it.

Earlier it was compiling but I was getting a Collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status. To get around it I tried moving the section above into my main.c just to check but ended up in this world of pain.

I get the messages are telling me I am redefining a function, but you use the right click find all and it just references itself so I'm at a loss.

*EDIT*

Here is an example of one of the compiler errors:
[image]

And my CMAKE file
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0)
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(TTGODemo)

EDIT2**

Ok so taking the comments on board, I removed the second include of BTKeyboard out of the ESP_HID_GAP.H i had. I had put it in there to cover a static constant char that was declared in only bluetoothkeyboard.h so idk how they were communicating.

That was done, I got the following wall of Text:
[image]

I think there are functions in the Bluetooth libraries that are also in the esp_hid_gap.h that it's getting hung up on. But i don't really know what to do about it, i could try removing the BT libraries but that will probably make things worse.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you look at the compiler output, don't you get some information "... first defined here..." for your redefined identifiers? The file `bluetoothkeyboard.h` from the link does not contain include guards. You might accidentally include it twice. And it even contains function definitions.

Comment: Is seems like `bluetoothkeyboard.h` isn't meant to be included anywhere else. You can add `#pragma once` and make all functions there `inline` functions. But not sure if there are some other caveats then.

Comment: It looks as if the header files are compiled independently, i.e. as the primary input to the compiler instead of indirectly via inclusion into .c or .cpp files. In order to help you, you need to provide more information about the project setup: What tools do you use to compile the code? What do the *CMakeLists.txt* or similar look like? What is the directory structure of your project?

Comment: HI team thanks for the comments, i have added the extra information you suggested. I thought about the include once thing mentioned as well, so messed around with having it so it's only in my Main.c (or networking.c wherever i choose to use it) but then i get src/BTKey/esp_hid_gap.h: In function 'esp_hid_scan':
src/BTKey/esp_hid_gap.h:836:18: error: 'TAG' undeclared (first use in this function) if i don;t have bluetoothkeyboard.h in esp_HID_GAP.h, and i just go in circles

Comment: Please post the relevant code, in particular *bluetoothkeyboard.h* and *esp_hid_gap.h*. You have obviously modified these files as the error messages no longer match the files on GitHub. In addition, *bluetoothkeyboard.h* is problematic as it contains variable and function definitions in a header file. This only makes sense in very specific setups. And I doubt it is documented what this setup is.

Comment: Post code and output as text (instead of as images). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/413337

Comment: @Codo thanks for the update, i couldn't fit the code into a post so i uploaded it to my github. https://github.com/NZjeux26/AssignmentThreeBT1/tree/main/TTGODemo-2/

It's a mixture of my code, the library BTKey and then the rest is my lecturers' code i'm using as a base.

Comment: As the BLE code you're using is structured in a very special way and as it's not documented how it is supposed to be used, I recommend to switch to alternative code that has either best practice structure or its usage is documented. If you still want to make it work with this code, you need to familiarize yourself in depth with C/C++ concepts such as definition vs declaration, #ifdef patterns for headers files that are included multiple times etc. The main thing is however: unlike regular header files `bluetoothkeyboard.h` and `esp_hid_gap.h` contain definitions and must only be included once.